# Click event in below code not working when `<app-tab-nav>` component is included

Tags: css, ionic-framework, z-index

Click event in below code not working when `<app-tab-nav>` component is included

```html
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <div id="container">
    <ion-button (click)="logout()">Logout</ion-button>
  </div>
</ion-content>

<app-tab-nav activeTab="home"></app-tab-nav>
```

Any idea what could be issue here?

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: What's `app-tab-nav`?

Comment: it's a custom component that i wrote

Comment: Got it... Do you think you could create a Stackblitz demo with your code? Otherwise it will imposible to know why that custom component is creating an issue in the content of the page. You can use **[this starter](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-starter-app)** if you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue was in the css, Problem is fixed after adding `z-index:1`

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index:1;
}
```